# this is not working, static css and JavaScript using pug

Tags: node.js, pug

pug

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        title created with pug
        
    body 
//here this is css file not working
        link(rel="stylesheet", source="app.css")
//here this is JavaScript file not working
        script src="use.js" 
     
    h1#hello.my   this is  h1 
    p.hello  my para
```

i already use node js files for this so i am only concerned about this
also i am a beginner so try to give easy answers if possile.
have a good day!

Comment: "not working" is not a proper problem description. *What* is "not working" ? Do you have any error message, or how is the actual result different from the expected result?

Comment: problem with mime types

Comment: What does a pug template have to do with mimetypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is correct pug syntax for `link`  and `script` tags

```
link(rel='stylesheet' href='app.css')
script(src="use.js")
```

The correct pug comment begin with `//-`

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        title Created with pug

        //- here is css
        link(rel='stylesheet' href='app.css')
        //- here is JavaScript
        script(src="use.js")
    body 
        h1#hello.my This is h1 
        p.hello My para
```

Comment: good but not my answer:)